# concatinating multiple strings from dictionary and save in file using python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I able to write hostname in the /tmp/filter.log but any hint how can i write all three values[hostname, owner, seats] in the file?

```
def list_hosts(nc):
    resp = nc.send_service_request('ListHosts', json.dumps({}))
    result = resp['result']
    l = []
    f=open("/tmp/filter.log", "w+")
    for r in result:
        if "team-prod" in r['owner']:
            print r['owner'], r['hostname'], r['seats']
            f.write(r['hostname'] + "\n")
    f.close()
    l.append(r['hostname']) 
    return l
nc = create_client('zone', 'team_PROD_USERNAME', 'team_PROD_PASSWORD')
l = list_hosts(nc)
print l
```

The file should have entries as below:

```
team-prod\*, np-team-052, [u'123123123-18d1-483d-9af8-169ac66b26e4']
```

Current entry is:

```
np-team-052
```

Comment: Is the code indented properly?

Comment: the whole code is messed up. `result` is not visible outside of the function. The indentation doesn't make sense

Comment: Code is working for me to fulfill my need at the moment. All i need is the way to write all the three keys in my print to the log file. 

I tried this but get error:

    f.write(r['owner'] + ', ' + r['hostname'] + ', ' + r['seats'] + '\n')

    File "listhost-prod-gpu.py", line 46, in <module>
    l = list_hosts(nc)
    File "listhost-prod-gpu.py", line 40, in list_hosts
    f.write(r['owner'] + ', ' + r['hostname'] + ', ' + r['seats'] + '\n')
   TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Comment: Can you show a sample of `print r['owner'], r['hostname'], r['seats']
`?

Comment: actually, figured out this helped me.

    f.write(str(r['owner']) + ', ' + str(r['hostname']) + ', ' + str(r['seats']) + '\n')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f.write(str(r['owner']) + ', ' + str(r['hostname']) + ', ' + str(r['seats']) + '\n')

Comment: output:
team-prod\*, np-team-052, [u'123123123-483d-9af8-169ac66b26e4']